# Matplotlib- Add a color bar below a multi-colored line subplot as shown in the image

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I am having a multicolored line plot and I want to add a color bar under it in the same figure like as shown in the image below, Is it possible?

I have attached a color bar image as a reference which I took from another code.
My intention here is to use the color bar like a legend for each segment of the line in the plot.

Edit-1: I want to have the color bar using a mappable object such as an image, So don't want to create a new subplot for the sole purpose of the color bar.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in Advance.

[image: Multicoloredline plot]
[image: Required Colorbar]

This is the code for multicolored line plot

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
Segments=[[[3,1],[6,1]],[[6,2],[9,2]],[[9,3],[12,3]],[[12,4],[15,4]], [[12,4],[15,4]]]         
Points_1 = np.concatenate([Segments[:-1], Segments[1:]], axis=1) 
lc = LineCollection(Points_1, colors=['r','g','b','y'], linewidths=2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.add_collection(lc)   
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The code you're providing is not runnable.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some part of the code. I updated it now.  Actually, I want to have the color bar with only 1 subplot by using a mappable object such as an image, because the code which I am dealing with can have m*n subplots, and the color bar will represent for all the subplots. Could you suggest how to reproduce the same color bar with a mappable object?  Sorry for the incomplete requirement given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround I'am using:

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.colorbar as mcolorbar
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors



Segments=[[[3,1],[6,1]],[[6,2],[9,2]],[[9,3],[12,3]],[[12,4],[15,4]], [[12,4],[15,4]]]         
Points_1 = np.concatenate([Segments[:-1], Segments[1:]], axis=1) 
lc = LineCollection(Points_1, colors=['r','g','b','y'], linewidths=2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios' : [5,1]}) 
ax[0].add_collection(lc)

bounds = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)[:-1]
labels = ['Action1', 'Action2', 'Action3', 'Action4']
ax[0].set_xlim([0, 15])
ax[0].set_ylim([0, 10])
cb2 = mcolorbar.ColorbarBase(ax = ax[1], cmap = cmap, orientation = 'horizontal', extendfrac='auto')
cb2.set_ticks(bounds)
cb2.set_ticklabels(labels)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you specifically want to avoid subplots, you can use a scalar mappable:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.add_collection(lc)   
ax.autoscale()
cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['r','g','b','y'])
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap) 
sm.set_array([]) # this line may be ommitted for matplotlib >= 3.1 
cbar = fig.colorbar(sm, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal',aspect=90)
bounds = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)[:-1]
labels = ['Action1', 'Action2', 'Action3', 'Action4']
ax.set_xlim([0, 15])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])
cbar.set_ticks(bounds)
cbar.set_ticklabels(labels)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Liris. Actually, I want to have the color bar with only 1 subplot by using a mappable object such as an image, because the code which I am dealing with can have m*n subplots, and the color bar will represent for all the subplots. Could you suggest how to reproduce the same color bar with a mappable object?  Sorry for the incomplete requirement given.

Comment: I am not sure to understand why you can't extrapolate this example to your case. Here, the colorbar is created completely artificially a posteriori. Could you give an example of how you create your multiple subplots ?

Comment: Thanks Liris. After further research with your answer. 
I have added these three lines to get desired color bar.                                           `sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array([]) 
cbar=fig.colorbar(sm, ax=ax, ticks=c, orientation='horizontal',aspect=90)`

Comment: Alright ! I edited my answer using this solution, you may accept it for further use by other people if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to get what I asked.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors    
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

Segments=[[[3,1],[6,1]],[[6,2],[9,2]],[[9,3],[12,3]],[[12,4],[15,4]], [[12,4],[15,4]]]         
Points_1 = np.concatenate([Segments[:-1], Segments[1:]], axis=1) 

lc = LineCollection(Points_1, colors=['r','g','b','y'], linewidths=2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.add_collection(lc)   
ax.autoscale()

c=[1,2,3,4,5]
labels = ['Action1', 'Action2', 'Action3', 'Action4']

cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['r','g','b','y'])
norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm([1,2,3,4,5],4)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array([])  # this line may be ommitted for matplotlib >= 3.1
cbar=fig.colorbar(sm, ticks=c, orientation='horizontal')

cbar.set_ticklabels(['Action1', 'Action2', 'Action3', 'Action4'])
plt.show()
```

[image: Output plot]